# Error log file feof(),fgets() using PHP

Tags: php, file, error-handling, hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

I have the `PHP` code as below:

```
<?php
$PMTA = $_GET['PMTA'];
//Get current date
$date = date('Y-m-d');
// Declare variables
$chart = array();
$title = "";
$domain = "";
$total = array();
$fail = array();
$cate = array();
$orderChart = array();
$container ="";
$dormain_str = array(); 
// End declare variable 

//Use switch for getting the text files                 
    switch($PMTA){
        case 1:

            if(file_exists('../pmta/stats_domain_emetteur_recepteur.unitead.info.'.$date.'.txt'))
            {
                $file = '../pmta/stats_domain_emetteur_recepteur.unitead.info.'.$date.'.txt';
            }
            else
            {
                $file = 'file_exits/stats_domain_sender_blank.txt';
            }
            break;
        case 2:

            if(file_exists('../pmta/stats_domain_emetteur_recepteur.frdcrp.com.'.$date.'.txt'))
            {
                $file = '../pmta/stats_domain_emetteur_recepteur.frdcrp.com.'.$date.'.txt';
            }
            else
            {
                $file = 'file_exits/stats_domain_sender_blank.txt';
            }
            break;
        case 3:

            if(file_exists('../pmta/stats_domain_emetteur_recepteur.affinitead.net.'.$date.'.txt'))
            {
                $file = '../pmta/stats_domain_emetteur_recepteur.affinitead.net.'.$date.'.txt';
            }
            else
            {
                $file = 'file_exits/stats_domain_sender_blank.txt';
            }
            break;
        case 4:

            if(file_exists('../pmta/stats_domain_emetteur_recepteur.switchcall.com.'.$date.'.txt'))
            {
                $file = '../pmta/stats_domain_emetteur_recepteur.switchcall.com.'.$date.'.txt';
            }
            else
            {
                $file = 'file_exits/stats_domain_sender_blank.txt';
            }
            break;
        case 5:

            if(file_exists('../pmta/stats_domain_emetteur_recepteur.unitead.eu.'.$date.'.txt'))
            {
                $file = '../pmta/stats_domain_emetteur_recepteur.unitead.eu.'.$date.'.txt';
            }
            else
            {
                $file = 'file_exits/stats_domain_sender_blank.txt';
            }
            break;

    }

                // Open the file and read data
                $files = fopen($file,'r');
                // Start i = 0  
                $i = 0;
                // Check for the end of file has been reached,if have any error or end of file it will return true, other will return false
                while(!feof($files)){
                    // It breaks the string in file that seperate by ; into array, so $data will become an array
                    $data = explode(";",fgets($files));
                    // Determind wheather the data is not empty or not
                    if(!empty($data[6])){
                        $domain = $data[6];
                            if(!empty($_POST['txt_order_blue'])){                                       
                                $orderChart[$domain][] =array("success" => (100 - $data[9]),"fail" =>(float)$data[9],"cate" => $data[5]);                                       
                            }
                                // Else if click on button order by % failed        
                            else{
                                $orderChart[$domain][] =array("fail" =>(float)$data[9],"success" => (100 - $data[9]),"cate" => $data[5]);   
                           }                             
                        $i++;

                    }   

                }

?>
```

When I run in local it works fine,but when I run it on the server it show the message

```
[Thu Dec 27 09:12:37 2012] [error] [client 103.23.136.12] PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/uniteadpro/www/kama/stats/unitead_chart/bar_chart_ratio_recepteur_emetteur.php on line 89
```

And

```
[Thu Dec 27 09:12:37 2012] [error] [client 103.23.136.12] PHP Warning:  fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/uniteadpro/www/kama/stats/unitead_chart/bar_chart_ratio_recepteur_emetteur.php on line 90, referer: http://www.unitead.pro/kama/stats/unitead_chart/
```

In log files.
I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: You are *not* handling errors. Check if `fopen($file)` succeeded before passing it around as a file handle.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file "file_exits/stats_domain_sender_blank.txt" exist on same location as "bar_chart_ratio_recepteur_emetteur.php".

I guess your both files must be at "/home/uniteadpro/www/kama/stats/unitead_chart/" location. For second error just remove while loop.